# Can we set multiple hydrator for one zend\form?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Why? Because, I want to use them for attaching more than one Model/Entity for one Form.

What I think? In my opinion I have to get all data in one Model/Entity and then populate in multiple Tables (using Mapper or Gateway) but logically a Model is for one Table.

What is my proposed solution? So for adding one Form data in multiple tables, I have to use two Models. But in ZF2, a form can have one Hydrator using $form->setHydrator.

What I want to know? Any other possibility for this porblem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using formCollections?

Basically you would make a fieldset for each entity, with its own fields and hydrator. Then make one form that includes these fieldsets.

Much like the tutorial here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html

( I'm on my mobile phone right now so examples are hard to give, if you need me to elaborate, let me know )

Comment: Great idea, the forms already used fieldset and collections (for relations) but I did not used hydrators in them. I was thinking AggregateHydrator as a solution of it. Let me put your nickle on them. Thanks. :)

Comment: An AggregateHydrator just runs through a set of hydrators in order. But it still would only fill one object at a time. Meaning you would have say two hydrators, which hydrate different entities but are still used for each object. That's unneeded overhead ;) although, it would probably have worked! ;)